# C# Clear List if Count = 0

Tags: c#, .net

I was looking through some existing code and noticed that they had this section of code

```
if (values.Count ==0){
    values.Clear();
}
```

Where values is a List<'a> according to visual studio.

As far as I understand it, this section is saying "if list is empty, then empty it". If this is the case does that not make this section of code redundant, because if the list is empty then it doesn't need to be cleared?

Am I correct in assuming this? Or is this code section actually doing something else and needs to be kept?

Comment: Yes, You're correct - I would suspect the author intended a != though ...

Comment: Hmm, I thought as much. It's strange as they've used that exact segment for just about every list they make

Comment: What do the unit tests that cover this chunk of code have to say about it? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Clear() method of a list removes all elements. As the count (of elements) is zero, this code is effectively redundant.

However, the code should be viewed in the context of the wider routine in which it exists, so as to perhaps understand what it 'should' do rather than what it doesn't.

Comment: nit: `Clear()` isn't an extension method (unless we're talking past eachother)

Comment: Indeed Marc, well noted. I've updated my answer accordingly! :)